# Join pivot-tables, rename columns. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, pivot

I have below query which selects from a table containing date, currency, mvcleanccy and spotsek.

Question 1. How do I rename the columns so from DKK, EUR... to DKK_MV, EUR_MV.

Question 2. I have the same pivot with the only difference that `'MV_SEK' = mvcleanccy*spotsek` is replaced by `MV = mvcleanccy`. 
If I want to join these two pivots on position date in the query, how do I do that without creating two seperate tables and joining afterwards?

```
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT 
    currency 
    ,'MV_SEK' = mvcleanccy*spotsek
    ,todaypositiondate
from T1
) as src
PIVOT
(
 sum(MV_SEK)
for
currency in ([DKK], [EUR], [NOK], [SEK], [USD])
)
as pivottable
Order by todaypositiondate desc
```

Comment: Question 2 is completely unclear

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Your query is non-standard SQL.

Comment: SQL 2008 R2 (SP1)... old i know

Comment: "SQL" is a query language, not a DBMS product (so there is no product "SQL 2008"). But I guess you are referring to "SQL **Server** 2008"

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT currency, [DKK] as [DKK_MV], [EUR] as [EUR_MV], [NOK] as [NOK_MV], [SEK] as [SEK_MV], [USD] as [USD_MV] -- this should rename the columns as per question 1

FROM(
SELECT 
    currency 
    ,'MV_SEK' = mvcleanccy*spotsek
    ,todaypositiondate
from T1
) as src
PIVOT
(
 sum(MV_SEK)
for
currency in ([DKK], [EUR], [NOK], [SEK], [USD])
)
as pivottable
Order by todaypositiondate desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution would be simpler with conditional aggregation:

```
select todaypositiondate,
       sum(case when currency = 'DKK' then mvcleanccy * spotsek end) as dkk_mv,
       sum(case when currency = 'EUR' then mvcleanccy * spotsek end) as eur_mv,
       . . .
       sum(case when currency = 'DKK' then mvcleanccy end) as dkk,
       sum(case when currency = 'EUR' then mvcleanccy end) as eur,
       . . .
from t1
group by todaypositiondate
order by todaypositiondate;
```